# Configure apache server to run Python in special tags (like PHP)

Tags: php, python-3.x, apache

Is it possible to configure an Apache webserver to use execute Python in the same way as PHP? Meaning, you could execute python code in a `<?python3 ?>` tag just like you can execute PHP in `<?php ?>` tags.  I am *not* asking about WSGI or CGI.
Here's an example of what it would look like in Python3:
**magic_number.py**:

```
<?python3
import math
number = math.sqrt(42)
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Magic number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The magic number is <?python3 print(number)?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The same code in PHP would look like this:
**magicNumber.py**:

```
<?php
$number = sqrt(42);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Magic number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The magic number is <?php echo $number; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is possible, how could I configure it to work in Apache?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you ever seen it done that way?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope!

Comment: It's possible to do on your server side machine. But not in the way of using Apach server itself. If it's ok to you I can briefly explain how to.

Comment: @GensaGames yes, please do explain how!

Answer (score 1):

You can create behavior you want, but I'm not sure it's a perfect way to solve end task you are trying to do.

1. The way what would render your `php` script. It will be your entry point. I think it's Web page itself, which mean that you need to call shell. For ex.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("python embedded.py");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....
```

2. Now above will execute file, which is not exist yet. To create it, you would need to call `php` to create file from string. **Below complete snippet.**

```
<?php
// Create file with Python source
$embedded = <<<EOF
import math
number = math.sqrt(42)
EOF;

// Save file somewhere
file_put_contents("embedded.py", $embedded);

// Execute shell on Server side
$output = shell_exec("python embedded.py");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....
```

Comment: How can I get a variable from PHP into the Python script?

Comment: @NoahBroyles If you check any getting started guide with python, you will know how to supply params during shell `execute` and then you can parse inside scripts with `sys.args`.

Comment: Oh okay, pass it as a param in the shell.

Comment: @NoahBroyles Right.

Comment: Wall I reckon' that's pretty useful.

Comment: Obviously there is no other implementation for such kind of behavior like you want with `?python`. However it's not a problem to do, like I described above. Let me know, if it suites your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Castalian](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Castalian), which uses a cgi handler for it, letting you embed python code inside `<?cas … ?>`.

Sadly, it is made for use with python2 and I can't find an update that works with python3. If someone knows, please edit or comment.

Another way might be PSP, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2132383/43615).